# BSOD irql_not_less_or_equal_on Windows Server 2012 after KB4586808, KB4586834

Tags: bsod, windows-server-2012

I have a production system (Windows Server 2012) that gave BSOD with error "IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL". It seems to have happened under higher than usual load.

The server is critical and I could not wait for the memory dump to complete before rebooting. The part of the memory.dump file that I have does not help because it is corrupt.The same thing happend two more times within 24 hours. The only change to the system since the last high load day was the Windows Server 2012 November 2020 Microsoft patches (KB4586808, KB4586834). I Uninstalled the patches and the server has been running stable for 100 hours since uninstalling the mentioned patches and processing higher that usual volumes.

This server has been installed 4 years ago on the same hardware and we have not seen this error before. This server is very sensitive and sits inside a secure network with strict access, realtime firewall monitoring and the security is frequently audited by an external auditor.

This server is a VM running on a Microsoft's Hypervizer (also server 2020) on FT Stratus hardware. There is another Windows 2020 VM on the same host that does not have this problem but it's applications do almost nothing.

(The only other variable that I can think of is that the Solarwinds hack happened on the same day - but we are not running Orion so it cannot be related).

Basically my question is this: Has anybody experienced this error on Windows Server 2012 after installing the November 2020 Microsoft patches?

Comment: Are you able to clone the machine to set it up "offline", before trying to reproduce and be able to get the dump file?

Comment: .i tried it by sending 4 x the production load experienced at the time.Trend Apecs was active at the time. I cannot force this error on the cloned environment yet.